# Many django projects with one admin for all

Tags: django

I have many django projects witch looks the same: there are some Config models and some models user actions Results.
The task is to make a one point of Config models contol, keep the history of changes and have authorization (let's call this project Control UI). And I think django admin will be good for it and django-reversion for changes history.

What is the best architecture for projects and Control UI interaction?

My thoughts:

1. For every project make a connection to Control UI database and keep Config models there. I'll set Control UI as a package dependency for each project and use Config models from the app made for current project.
2. The same with a connection to Control UI database but models are kept in projects and Control UI has all the projects as dependencies. This is the easiest to implement, but Conftol UI may have conflicts in dependencies as each project may use different version of some module.
3. Do nothing with DBs. Make a REST API for each project and make models based on API calls in Control UI. I need models to use in admin. I haven't tested yet, but look like django-reversion won't work for Config models if they will be over API.

Any other options?